# Flipping an image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flip

Before you tune out and label this as a dreadful question, please listen, I am aware that there are [many](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jQuery%20rotating&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=jQuery%20flipping%20an%20image&oq=jQuery%20flipping%20an%20image&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.269775.273619.1.273750.24.13.0.10.10.0.290.1618.9j2j2.13.0...0.0...1c.mpvwQ7RKh9c&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=19e37c0ddddf3693&biw=1920&bih=950) jQuery plugins that flip images / content. My problem however involves something a little more difficult.

My problem is that a client wants their logo to constantly flip at a slow rate (this is not much of a problem) but when the logo is  flipped halfway, instead of the image having 0 width they want the logo to appear a little "3D" so that when you are viewing it head on, it actually has a width.

I've googled around a bit but really can't seem to find a plug-in that achieves this, is it even possible?

If you're having trouble visualising what I mean when I say flip, see this [demo](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php)

Comment: The 3D part isn't going to happen if all you've got is CSS/JS and a flat image. You'd need to render that sort of animation in bespoke fashion, with keyframes etc.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case

Comment: The demo should work - just click a tile

Comment: OK it worked on Chrome of my system...

Comment: So basically, there's no easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/ but with a very narrow "cube"? Or something like this http://www.tutorials007.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/3d_text_5.gif ? Maybe you could clone the panel to be rotated, and at halfway of the animation, you could spread them horizontally.

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do when the animation is half way. please elaborate or may be attach some mockups of what you want us to visualize..

Comment: Ok, I'll try and explain, say on this page: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php when you click a tile it rotates, when the tile is exactly halfway it dissapears (it's width is zero) but is only dissapears for a split second. Basically instead of it dissapearing for that split second I want it to have a small width when it is facing you head on, and for that width to have a BG colour. If that doesn't make sense let me know and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Note the demo you linked to did not actually flip the logo, merely the container of it. All of that is possible, just not the 3D part you describe.

Comment: It was meant to be an example to help you visualise flipping, I did not say it was flipping a logo . . . and yes I know everything I want is possible, the question was is the 3D bit possible, it seems the answer to that is no.

Comment: AFAIK there is no extrusion possible with css and js. You'd have to use a software and save the steps out as Utkanos said. Try looking into Photoshop's 3d features or After Effects or even a 3D tool like modo or Lightwave. 3d transforms by themselves only work in newer browsers anyway - so no IE8 and below support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we gave up on a JavaScript solution (it was going to be near impossible to have a reasonable cross browser solution)

So we ended up using [jquery reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) to accomplish this (why we didn't think of sprites earlier I'll never know!)

Answer (score 1):

I have found some 3D Flipping image examples, so please try for it.

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel

http://www.360-javascriptviewer.com/learning-centre/code-examples/multiple-360-images-page.html

http://blog.stableflow.com/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/

if you wan to create codebins for it then click on link http://codebins.com/